# A toArray function that breaks on primitive type, but works fine when written as a PartialFunction?

Tags: scala, scala-reflect, partialfunction

Playing around with a reflection-base code I've come a cross a situation where I want to convert a sequence into array. The catch is that the only type information available is in the form of a `runtime.universe.Type`, and the sequence itself is of type `Seq[Any]`.

I attempted to call the `toArray` method on the Seq, which requires a `ClassTag` that I don't have. Naively I just created a `ClassTag[Any]` out of the runtime Type, like this:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

def anyClassTag(tpe: ru.Type) = ClassTag[Any](mirror.runtimeClass(tpe))

def toArray1(items: Seq[Any]) = (tpe: ru.Type) => {
  items.toArray(anyClassTag(tpe))
}
```

Unsurpisingly this fails with a `CastClassException` when called with a primitive type.

```
toArray1(Seq(1,2,3))(ru.typeOf[Int]) foreach print // java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

However, if the function is rewritten as a `PartialFunction` instead, then it somehow works!

```
def toArray2(items: Seq[Any]) : PartialFunction[ru.Type, Array[Any]] = { case tpe =>
  items.toArray(anyClassTag(tpe))
}

toArray2(Seq(1,2,3))(ru.typeOf[Int]) foreach print // Successfully prints 123 !
```

This seems to be very fragile though. A slight modification could easily break it again. Example:

```
def toArray3(items: Seq[Any]) : PartialFunction[ru.Type, Array[Any]] = { case tpe =>
  val results = items.toArray(anyClassTag(tpe))
  results
}

toArray3(Seq(1,2,3))(ru.typeOf[Int]) foreach print // ClassCastException again!
```

So the question is, what magic is going on here? Why is `toArray2` the only one that work, and should it?

Comment: Runtime reflection in Scala is slow and has a number severe of bugs, including regressions. Please check your Scala version with a list of opened or recently closed bugs: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Areflection+